# How can I both hide and override inherited method in F#?

Tags: f#

I want to create mockable handler for `HttpClient`, so I define it like this:

```
type TestHandler() = 
    inherit HttpMessageHandler()
    abstract SendAsync: HttpRequestMessage * CancellationToken -> Task<HttpResponseMessage>
    override this.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken) = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
```

but I get the error:

> Error FS0361
>   The override `SendAsync : HttpRequestMessage * CancellationToken -> Task<HttpResponseMessage>` 
>   implements more than one abstract slot, 
>   e.g. `abstract member TestHandler.SendAsync : HttpRequestMessage * CancellationToken -> Task<HttpResponseMessage>`
>   and 
>   `HttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(request: HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken: CancellationToken) : Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

My intent is to create public overridable method which can be mocked with Foq, and which is simply called in base `SendAsync`.

If I name abstract method differently, e.g. `MockableSendAsync` compiler does not complain, but is it possible to reuse the name? (Is it possible to make method sealed?)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Would it not satisfy your requirement if you remove the `abstract` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the issue is that the virtual `SendAsync` method in `HttpMessageHandler` is `protected`, but want to create a type where it is `public` so that it can be mocked easily.

I don't think there is a way to hide virtual method with another new (public) virutal method in F#, but I think your use case would work if you defined a virutal method of some other name and called it from the original `SendAsync` method:

```
type TestHandler() = 
    inherit HttpMessageHandler()
    abstract MockableSendAsync: 
        HttpRequestMessage * CancellationToken -> Task<HttpResponseMessage>
    default this.MockableSendAsync(request, cancellationToken) = 
        base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
    override this.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken) = 
        this.MockableSendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Yeah, this [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671911/is-it-possible-to-simultaneously-hide-and-override-virtual-method) in C# as well